# Fill mbtiles with hatch instead of single colour

Tags: mbtiles

I'm using [tileserver-gl](https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl) to serve tiles. At the moment I am using `fill-color` to fill with one colour.

```
"fill-color": "rgba(230, 36, 0, 1)",
```

But now I need to fill with stripes, e.g `rgba(230, 36, 0, 1)`, `rgba(11, 111, 202)` and I can't figure out how to do this.

I tried creating an svg `stripes.svg` and replacing `fill-color` with `fill-pattern`, but when I do that nothing displays. I'd like to find out how to get my `stripes.svg` to display, or if there's a different approach I could be using to get the hatched fill.

original my_style.json (solid fill)

```
{
    "id": "my_style",
    "version": 1,
    "name": "my_style",
    "sources": {
        "mbtiles1": {
            "type": "vector",
            "url": "mbtiles://my_mbtiles.mbtiles"
        }
    },
    "layers": [
        {
            "id": "layer1",
            "type": "fill",
            "source": "mbtiles1",
            "source-layer": "cat1",
            "paint": {
                "outline-color": "rgba(230, 36, 0, 1)",
                "fill-color": "rgba(230, 36, 0, 1)",
                "fill-translate-anchor": "map"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

updated my_style.json (attempt to hatch fill, but nothing displays)

```
{
    "id": "my_style",
    "version": 1,
    "name": "my_style",
    "sources": {
        "mbtiles1": {
            "type": "vector",
            "url": "mbtiles://my_mbtiles.mbtiles"
        }
    },
    "layers": [
        {
            "id": "layer1",
            "type": "fill",
            "source": "mbtiles1",
            "source-layer": "cat1",
            "paint": {
                "fill-pattern": "stripes.svg"
                "fill-translate-anchor": "map"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

config.json

```
{
    "options": {
        "paths": {
            "root": "/data",
            "fonts": "fonts",
            "styles": "styles",
            "mbtiles": "/data"
        }
    },
    "styles": {
        "my_style": {
            "style": "my_style.json",
            "tilejson": {
                "bounds": [
                    -180,
                    -85.06,
                    180,
                    85.06
                ]
            }
        },
    }
}
```

Directory layout

```
├── my_mbtiles.mbtiles
├── config.json
├── fonts
│   └── __empty__dir__
├── stripes.svg
└── styles
    └── my_style.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I had to generate sprites from my svg. I used the [spritezero-docker] container (which uses [spritezero-cli](https://github.com/mapbox/spritezero-cli)) to do this.

This generates 3 json files and 3 png files. I moved them into a `sprites` directory, so my layout was:

```
├── my_mbtiles.mbtiles
├── config.json
├── fonts
│   └── __empty__dir__
├── sprites
│   ├── sprites@2x.json
│   ├── sprites@2x.png
│   ├── sprites@3x.json
│   ├── sprites@3x.png
│   ├── sprites.json
│   └── sprites.png
└── styles
    └── my_style.json
```

I then updated my style file. I added `"sprite": "sprites/sprites"` to reference the sprites file (no `.png` required). Then `"fill-pattern": "stripes"` filled my layer with the stripes pattern as required.

```
{
    "id": "my_style",
    "version": 1,
    "name": "my_style",
    "sources": {
        "mbtiles1": {
            "type": "vector",
            "url": "mbtiles://my_mbtiles.mbtiles"
        }
    },
    "sprite": "sprites/sprites"
    "layers": [
        {
            "id": "layer1",
            "type": "fill",
            "source": "mbtiles1",
            "source-layer": "cat1",
            "paint": {
                "fill-pattern": "stripes"
                "fill-translate-anchor": "map"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I found the [mbtile style reference](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/geoserver/styling/mbstyle/reference/spec.html#id13), and the [our-north-star](https://github.com/GlobalFishingWatch/map-vectortiles/blob/master/styles/our-north-star/our-north-star.json) repo useful for figuring out this answer.